# GObjectIntrospection Linking to libgirepository-internals and libgirepository-1.0

Tags: gtk

Trying to add tests to the gobject-introspection test suite to cover more of the functions and learn about the code.
wanted to create a simple test to create an object from the libgirepository_internals.a but having problems linking,
wondering if anyone can give me some advice on this ?

code is here, https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/gobject-introspection it is a simple branch of the master git://git.gnome.org/gobject-introspection adding some tests.

The project page for GObjectIntrospection is http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection

The test module that is not linking is : 
https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/gobject-introspection/blob/master/tests/repository/gitestenum.c

All I did was add in the extra lib :

```
$(top_builddir)/libgirepository-internals.la
gitestenum_SOURCES = $(srcdir)/gitestenum.c
gitestenum_CPPFLAGS = $(GIREPO_CFLAGS) -I$(top_srcdir)/girepository
gitestenum_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/libgirepository-1.0.la $(top_builddir)/libgirepository-internals.la $(top_builddir)/libgirepository-gthash.la $(GIREPO_LIBS)
```

here is the compiler errors:

```
CCLD   gitestenum
../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a(libgirepository_internals_la-girnode.o): In         function `_g_ir_node_get_full_size_internal':
gobject-introspection/girepository/girnode.c:629: undefined reference to         `g_type_tag_to_string'
../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a(libgirepository_internals_la-girnode.o): In function `serialize_type':
gobject-introspection/girepository/girnode.c:1198: undefined reference to `g_type_tag_to_string'
../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a(libgirepository_internals_la-girmodule.o):         In function `_g_ir_module_build_typelib':
gobject-introspection/girepository/girmodule.c:548: undefined reference to         `g_typelib_new_from_memory'
../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a(libgirepository_internals_la-giroffsets.o):         In function `get_type_size_alignment':
gobject-introspection/girepository/giroffsets.c:300: undefined reference to         `gi_type_tag_get_ffi_type'
../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a(libgirepository_internals_la-giroffsets.o): In function `get_enum_size_alignment':
gobject-introspection/girepository/giroffsets.c:174: undefined reference to `g_type_tag_to_string'
../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a(libgirepository_internals_la-giroffsets.o):         In function `get_type_size_alignment':
gobject-introspection/girepository/giroffsets.c:311: undefined reference to `g_type_tag_to_string'
```

What is bothering me is that the symbols are there :

```
gobject-introspection/.libs$ nm libgirepository-1.0.so | grep g_type_tag_to_string
    0000f0c0 T g_type_tag_to_string

gobject-introspection/.libs$ nm libgirepository-1.0.a | grep g_type_tag_to_string
    U g_type_tag_to_string
    00001e00 T g_type_tag_to_string
             U g_type_tag_to_string
```

And here is the internal linker command 
`/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --as-needed --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -z relro -o         .libs/gitestenum /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib -L/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../.. gitestenum-gitestenum.o --export-dynamic ../../.libs/libgirepository-1.0.so ../../.libs/libgirepository-internals.a -lm -ldl /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so -lffi /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so -lrt /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lpthread -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/crtend.o         /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crtn.o`

thanks,
mike

<strike>This message was posted to the Mailing list: gtk-devel-list@gnome.org but is awaiting moderation, I am posting it here for getting quick help.</strike>
this message was posted to the gtk devel list http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2012-March/msg00060.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved, was #-export-symbols-regex '^gi?_' 
code commited here https://github.com/h4ck3rm1k3/gobject-introspection/commit/9dc11f8a42e66797db7ed015ac5f2703435f4456